# google pie chart - labels are too far from from the center

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google graphs to draw a pie. The problem is that the labels with the percents are too far away from the center of the pie, and I can't find a way to bring them closer. Setting height and width doesn't help(I'm using this from inside an angular directive if it makes any difference):

```
            var options = {
                title  : 'My Title',
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('my-pie'));

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Moblie Type', 'count'],
                  ['Android',     11],
                  ['iPhone',      2]
            ]);

            chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: there are no [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) for placement of `pieSliceText`

Comment: I see the problem now. Only when I load the data for the pie using ajax, the labels are not positioned correctly. If I set the data for the chart right away when my controller loads, the positions of the labels are fine. However, the data must be loaded via ajax, so there will be some delay...Any solution to this?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the problem. will you share an image? are you able to re-draw the chart once the page is loaded? Or set dummy data in Controller (zeroes / nulls) then redraw when data loads? Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by wrapping the code inside my directive's link function with a $timeout. Probably the DOM wasn't fully ready when the draw ran for the first time.